# How to include rows with missing data in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have a table a table of `employees` and another `employee_address`.

Additionally, I have a table of `employee_email_address` (employees don't have to have an email)

```
select 
    employee.emp_id, 
    employee_address.address, 
    employee_email_address.email
from  
    employees 
inner join
    employee_address on employee.emp_id = employee_address.emp_id
inner join 
    employee_email_address on employee_email_address.emp_id = employee.emp_id
```

but what this query is giving me is only the employees who have an address AND an email address....

How can I include rows for which there is no `email_address` for the employees? (Note, the email address is not null)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left join instead of inner join.

Comment: I did, and it is still not adding these fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
Select e.emp_id, ea.address, eea.email
from employees e left join
     employee_address ea
     on ea.emp_id = e.emp_id left join
     employee_email_address eea 
     on eea.emp_id = e.emp_id;
```